# Display all products by category

Tags: api, woocommerce, categories

I am using REST API of woocommerce REST API , i want to get product by category . 
 I have a category called "Beverages" and there are 3 products in the category. Now I want to display all the products from category "Beverages".
How will I do that?

Comment: please help me to solve this issue